# Waiting for a callback method to be called in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, callback

I am writing an android application which interacts with a sensor using bluetooth and obtains temperature values. I am doing this by calling connectGatt() which is asynchronous and calls a callback once the connection is established. The problem I am facing is that my code has to wait until the connection gets established.

This is the implementation of the method which is being used in the code below.

```
public boolean connect(final String address)
{
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"IN CONNECT METHOD"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    if(btadapter == null || address == null)
    {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Unable to get Bluetooth Adapter or Address is not valid");
        return false;
    }
    if(address != null && address.equals(btaddress) && btgatt != null)
    {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Trying to connect to a bt gatt profile directly");
        boolean result = btgatt.connect();
        if(result)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    btdevice = btadapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    if(btdevice == null)
    {
        Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Could not find device.");
        return false;
    }
    btgatt = btdevice.connectGatt(this,false,btgattcallback);
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,btgatt.toString());
    btaddress = address;
    Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Connecting to the device");
    btConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
    return true;
}
```

Currently I could solve this problem by writing the following code in a handler thread as I don't want to block the UI thread while waiting for the callback. But I am not convinced with the approach.

```
        if(mLocation != null)
        {
            connect(btaddress);   // Method encapsulates calls to connectGatt method.
            while (btConnectionState != STATE_CONNECTED) {
                continue;
            }
            while (!services_discovered) {
                continue;
            }
            //Other Code
```

I feel that there could be better ways of solving this but couldn't find any on the web. I saw a couple of answers using CountDownLatch and Semaphores but I didn't understand them clearly.

Can anyone help me with understanding how to handle situations like these?
Thank you.

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to use actual async code.

Comment: @SLaks Pardon me, I didn't exactly get what you mean. Do you mean I should call the method which has the logic to be executed after connection establishes from the onConnectionStateChange() callback of connectGatt() method?

Comment: Use an android asynctask (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or Rx